# Pumping lemma $c^2a^nb^n$

Tags: regular-language

I'm trying to prove that the following language is not regular via the Pumping Lemma. But I don't know, why is my procedure wrong (choosen word is incorrect according to my teacher).

$$L= c^+ \cdot \left\{w \in \{a,b\}^* \mid \text{count of a's in w} = \text{count of b's in w}\right\}$$

I choose word $w=c^2a^nb^n$

$$
\begin{array}{l}
w = xyz \\
x = c^2a^l \\
y = a^k \\
z = a^{(n-k-l)}b^n
\end{array}$$

I have choosen $i=5$: then $w = c^2a^la^{5k}a^{(n-k-l)}b^n = c^2a^{(n+4k)}b^n \implies w $ is not from $L$ because $n+4k > n$

Why is $ca^nb^n$ good choice and $c^2a^nb^n$ is a bad choice?
Why I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: How do you knw that $|x|>2$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't know why. That's why ca^nb^n is good choice and c^2... is not? Is it because |c|>0 ?

Answer (score 2):

Watch out what the pumping lemma states!
There exists a natural number $n$ such that any word of length $\ge n$ can be written as $xyz$ such that $|xy|\le n$, $y\ne\epsilon$ and all $xy^iz$ with $i\ge 0$ are in $L$.

You want to consider $c^2a^nb^n\in L$. At least if $n\ge 2$, this *might* split as $x=c$, $y=c$, $z=a^nb^n$ (recall that we only have $|xy|\le n$, not $=n$). Now the pumping lemma gives us $ca^nb^n, c^3a^nb^n$ and so on - and that is not the desired contradiction as these actually are in $L$!

However, if you consider $ca^nb^n$, then these possibilities arise :

- $x=ca^k$, $y=a^l$ with $k\ge 0$, $l\ge1$, $k+1\le n$ leading to the contradiction e.g. $xy^0z=ca^{n-l}b^n\in L$.
- Or $x=\epsilon$, $y=ca^k$ with $0\le k\le n-1$, leading to the contradiction $xy^0z=a^{n-1}b^n\in L$.